# Environment variable not accessible in wsgi.py

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, wsgi

I want to have different `settings.py` files for the production and development environments for my Django project. For that, I have permanently added an environment variable(`DJANGO_ENV`) in the production environment based on which I am loading different settings.py. But for some reason, wsgi.py[code below] isn't accessing the environment variable hence the `if` condition is failing.

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

if os.environ.get("DJANGO_ENV") == "PROD":
#*this condition is failing for some reason
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']= 'myproject.settings_prod'
else:
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']= 'myproject.settings'

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

If I do `echo $DJANGO_ENV` on the terminal, I get "`PROD`" as the response, so the variable is set properly.

Also in the python shell, I can access the `DJANGO_ENV` variable.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get("DJANGO_ENV")
'PROD'
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Why didn't you just add the variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`?

Comment: @KlausD.thanks for replying. You mean I can set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in production environment to `myproject.settings_prod` ? and remove the if conditions?  Will the following work in local environment `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
?`

Comment: @KlausD. that is also not working. Basic problem is that environment variables aren't being accessed by wsgi.py. Do I need to restart my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to link the environment variables in `gunicorn.service` by setting them in a .env file like below.

```
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myproj
EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/myproj/.env
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/myproj/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/myproj.sock myproj.wsgi:application
```

In my .env I set the variable.

```
DJANGO_ENV="PROD"
```